# How to return to the previous frame with JOption Pane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

So i'm working on a project for school, in which I have created a database with the information for all the chemicals on the periodic table, and upon running the program, the user is prompted to pick between a few options, such as search, sort, etc. Like this:

```
 String[] options = new String[] {"Search", "Sort", "Add", "Delete", "Exit"};
    int x=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose one of the following:", "Virtual Periodic        Table", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);

    while (true)
    {
        if (options[x]=="Search")                           
        { 
            searchMenu();  
        }

        else if (options[x]=="Sort")
        {

        }

        else if (options[x]=="Add")
        {

        }

        else if (options[x]=="Delete")
        {

        }

        else if (options[x]=="Exit")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I am not quite finished, as of right now I am still working on the search option. Anyways, upon clicking the search option, I call a procedure which pops up another menu which prompts the user to specify what they would like to search by, like this:

```
 String[] options = new String[] {"Name", "Symbol", "Atomic Number", "Atomic Mass", "# of Valence     Electrons", "Go Back"};
    int x=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What would you like to search by?", "Virtual  Periodic Table", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);

    if (options[x]=="Name")                           
    { 
        searchByName();
    }

    else if (options[x]=="Symbol")
    {

    }

    else if (options[x]=="Atomic Number")
    {

    }

    else if (options[x]=="Atomic Mass")
    {

    }

    else if (options[x]=="# of Valence Electrons")
    {

    }      
    else if (options[x]=="Go Back")
    {

    }
```

Now, I am trying to figure out a way in which I can give the user the option to go back to the main menu so they can do something else with the data. For example if i decide to search but then i decide i want to actually sort, I can simply press "Go Back" and it will popup the previous menu, which was the main menu, so I can choose what I want to do next. I have added the button which says "Go Back" but i'm not quite sure how to make it so it actually gives command back to the main method which can popup the main menu again. I tried to put the search menu in a while loop and then making it break out of the loop if they were to click "Go Back" but it didn't no anything but close the entire program.

I'm still fairly new to GUI in Java, anybody know what i can do?

Comment: `options[x]=="Search"` is not how `String` comparison works in Java, you should be using `"Search".equals(options[x])`; Don't use a loop to repeat prompt the user, instead design a series of views which can be presented to the user using something like a `CardLayout` - Swing is not thread safe, so you shouldn't be playing around with the UI outside the EDT context nor using a loop within it as it will cause the UI to freeze...

Comment: It is not actually a string comparison, the user is not asked to enter any string, a GUI pops up with all of those options and depending on the one they click it will direct it to a certain procedure which will carry out that function. For actual string conversions I do indeed use the .equalsIgnoreCase command, although thank you for the useful pointer! Also as I mentioned I am not to savvy with GUI as of yet and am not sure how to use CardLayout, but I will definitely take a look into it!

Comment: You are comparison one `String` value with another `==` is bad practice and should be avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the ShowOptionDialog inside the while loop, so it will be called again when you leave the searchMenu

Comment: Thank you! Wow I feel really dumb now for not thinking about that.

Comment: :) a nice way to find this kind of problems is to run your project step by step with the debug tool of your IDE